# IDTech Unimag Card Swiper on Android | Timeout

Tags: android, cardreader

I'm trying to implement an Android Activity that detects the IDTech card reader accepts a simple card swipe.

Below is the bare bones structure to my implementation for which I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079050/idtech-unimag-card-swiper-on-android) as well

The code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import IDTech.MSR.XMLManager.StructConfigParameters;
import IDTech.MSR.uniMag.uniMagReader;
import IDTech.MSR.uniMag.uniMagReaderMsg;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements uniMagReaderMsg {

    private uniMagReader myUniMagReader = null;
    private Button btnSwipe;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(myUniMagReader == null) {
            myUniMagReader = new uniMagReader(this,this);
            myUniMagReader.setSaveLogEnable(false);
            myUniMagReader.setXMLFileNameWithPath(null);
            myUniMagReader.loadingConfigurationXMLFile(true);

            //myUniMagReader.setVerboseLoggingEnable(true);
            myUniMagReader.registerListen();
        }

        btnSwipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnSwipe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myUniMagReader.startSwipeCard();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    myUniMagReader.stopSwipeCard();
        myUniMagReader.unregisterListen();
        myUniMagReader.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUserGrant(int arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "getUserGrant -- " + arg1);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgAutoConfigProgress(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgAutoConfigProgress");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgCardData(byte arg0, byte[] arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgCardData");
        Log.d("UniMag", "Successful swipe!");
    }

    final Handler swipeHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String text = (String)msg.obj;
            TextView dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            dataView.setText(text);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgCommandResult(int arg0, byte[] arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgCommandResult");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgConnected() {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgConnected");
        Log.d("UniMag", "Card reader is connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgDisconnected() {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgDisconnected");
        if(myUniMagReader.isSwipeCardRunning()) {
            myUniMagReader.stopSwipeCard();
        }
        myUniMagReader.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgFailureInfo(int arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("UniMag","onReceiveMsgFailureInfo -- " + arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgSDCardDFailed(String arg0) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgSDCardDFailed -- " + arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgTimeout(String arg0) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgTimeout -- " + arg0);
        Log.d("UniMag","Timed out!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgToConnect() {
        Log.d("UniMag","Swiper Powered Up");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgToSwipeCard() {
        Log.d("UniMag","onReceiveMsgToSwipeCard");      
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveMsgAutoConfigCompleted(StructConfigParameters arg0) {
        Log.d("UniMag", "onReceiveMsgAutoConfigCompleted");
    }
}
```

The issue here is that I only get these two messages in the Logcat
"Swiper is powered up" from onReceiveMsgToConnect()

And After a few seconds (maybe 20 sec)

"Timed out!" from onReceiveMsgTimeout() that sends back a string saying unable to connect to device. I have multiple IDTech devices and this happens the same on every device. Also, sometimes if I am lucky enough I do get:
"Card reader is connected." from onReceiveMsgConnected() that means it is connected. But this happens very rarely.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Faizan I know this is an old post but I'm starting to work with Unimag now and to be honest I'm completely lost on how to start.
I've received the SDK and a manual but it doensn't seem to be a good way to start, I mean, their demo code has more than 4k code lines and I'm trying to start from the basic.
Where did you find information about the Unimag development? Is there anything else besides the sample code? Anyone found other example codes?? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I got it working. 
I was using an older version of the sdk (unimag.reader.android-1.0.0.jar) and the configuration xml file (idt_unimagcfg_default.xml). I simply updated them to the most recent version of the sdk and the xml.

New versions (as of December 2014)
SDK: IDT_UniMagSDKAndroid_v4.4.jar - xml: umcfg.4.4.1.xml

And the timeout problem is solved.

P.S: just as a side note, please also do visit their website for any device specific details you might need for the specific card swiper you are using. 
For example: I was using a "Shuttle, Two-Track Secure Mobile MagStripe Reader" with a "HTC ONE" phone. After going on to this page [here](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/141.html) I figured that for HTC ONE I need to turn off my "Beats audio" to appropriately use this device.
I hope this helps.

Comment: After December 2014 e is an update    **Updated 4/1/2015.

Please download XML file v1.15.8.20 to support Shuttle v2.x and earlier.

Please download XML file v5.0.2 to support Shuttle SDK v3.0 and later.**