# IDTech Unimag Swiper Android SDK Error

Tags: android, cardreader, unimag

I have to read the card on Swipe using UniMag Pro device .
i downloaded the `UniMag_SDK_v5.0.jar` . and doing the same as in below link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13654279/4466607
i have also tried :

```
myUniMagReader.setXMLFileNameWithPath(null);
```

and

```
// filePath :/data/data/com.example.braintech.myapplication/files/idt_unimagcfg_default.xml
 myUniMagReader.setXMLFileNameWithPath(filePath);
```

but i am getting the following error.

```
on D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-11 13:12:56.857 10176-10176/com.example.braintech.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map...

10-11 13:12:57.151 10176-10215/com.example.braintech.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8610_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                                 Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
                                                                                 Local Branch: 
                                                                                 Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
                                                                                 Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                 Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
10-11 13:12:57.166 10176-10215/com.example.braintech.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-11 13:12:57.199 10176-10215/com.example.braintech.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-11 13:12:57.237 10176-10176/com.example.braintech.myapplication W/UMSDK: SDK: reader attached, but no config loaded

10-11 13:13:04.911 10176-10453/com.example.braintech.myapplication D/MainActivity: FilePath :/data/data/com.example.braintech.myapplication/files/idt_unimagcfg_default.xml
10-11 13:13:05.002 10176-10186/com.example.braintech.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.908ms
10-11 13:13:05.391 10176-10453/com.example.braintech.myapplication D/UniMag: getUserGrant -- Checking if user grants downloading latest XML from Server.
10-11 13:13:05.392 10176-10176/com.example.braintech.myapplication D/Background: onPostExecute
10-11 13:13:18.618 10176-10176/com.example.braintech.myapplication W/UMSDK: SDK: Task not started: SDK config not loaded
```

When i connect device : i get error log :

```
 W/UMSDK: SDK: reader attached, but no config loaded
```

and when i start scan :

```
   myUniMagReader.startSwipeCard();
```

But i get this error :

```
W/UMSDK: SDK: Task not started: SDK config not loaded
```

Please help me to resolve this issue ..Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: Yes , I have done this . @Hetal

Comment: Thanks @Dhiru
I am able to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The UniMag documentation is weak, at the very best...so hopefully this helps someone since the above answer/comments are useless, and whatever link may have been referenced in the comments is no longer alive.

For me, 
when the Reader was attached prior to the activity being started,I would see the SDK logs report that the reader was attached, but
I would get this error once the activity started:

```
SDK: reader attached, but no config loaded
```

While the activity was active, if i removed and reattached the reader, it would update and work correctly allowing me to swipe cards...but I wanted the reader to be able to work correctly no matter when it was plugged in.

I got this working by simply adding:

```
myReader.connect();
```

right after the reader is initialized. Now my app works correctly and detects the reader even if it was plugged in before the app was launched.